# command not found after switching users

Tags: linux, debian, multiple-users

Using debian, (running as an image for docker container), I run these following [commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0457.png).

```bsh
user>>service 
(shows hints)
user>>su - root
root>>su - docker
user>>service 
(command not found)
```

So when logging to docker user, I can run the service command.
After switching to root and then back to docker user, the command is not found.

What is the explanation for this and what can I do to solve this problem?
is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Thank you, posted as text.